# What is the meaning of No man is an island

Tags: meaning, quotations, literature

### no man is an island

[image: mobile screenshot]

> No one is self-sufficient; everyone relies on others. This saying comes from a sermon by the seventeenth-century English author John Donne.
>   [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/no-man-is-an-island)

Is this it?
What is the meaning of *No man is an island*?

Comment: What does the definition provided in your screen shot not explain?

Comment: It seems to be referring to the Isle of No Man, instead of the Isle of Man. I can see how this could be a problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an interpretation of English literature.

Answer (score 1):

It means that humans are interdependent on each other, and when one human goes astray or dies, all of humanity is lessened.

The quote comes from John Donne, a 17th-century English clergyman, and the relevant passage is available at [www.quotationspage.com](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/29901.html):

> No man is an Island, entire of itself; every man is a piece of the
>   Continent, a part of the main; if a clod be washed away by the sea,
>   Europe is the less, as well as if a promontory were, as well as if a
>   manor of thy friends or of thine own were; any man's death diminishes
>   me, because I am involved in Mankind; And therefore never send to know
>   for whom the bell tolls; It tolls for thee.